# How to Style Required Message Inputs and Textarea

Tags: html, css, reactjs, contact-form, required-field

I'm currently making a contact page for my website in Reactjs, but how would I go about styling the required message when I click Submit? I want the message to appear directly below the input or textarea, but how do I do that?

**Relevent Code**

```html
<form className='contact-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    Fields marked with an <span className='red'>∗</span> are required.
    <div className='form-item'>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name <span className='red'>∗</span></label>
        <input className='name'
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required />
    </div>
    <div className='form-item'>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email <span className='red'>∗</span></label>
        <input className='email'
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required />
    </div>
    <div className='form-item'>
        <label htmlFor="subject">Subject <span className='red'>∗</span></label>
        <input className='subject'
            type="text"
            name="subject"
            value={this.state.subject}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required />
    </div>
    <div className='form-item'>
        <label htmlFor="message">Message <span className='red'>∗</span></label>
        <textarea name='message'
            rows='8'
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required />
    </div>
    <button className='btn' type='submit' disabled={this.state.disabled}>Submit</button>
    <div className={this.state.isSent ? 'message-open':'message'}>Message has been sent.</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation). There is a pseudo class named `invalid`.
You can put some text for this warning under each input element with an element you set to be `visibility` `hidden` in css. When they are `invalid` by your constraint, you can set them to be `visible`.

```
small {
  visibility: hidden;
}

small:invalid {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This works for every constraint. If you want only required to behave like that you can select them accordingly.

```
input:required + small {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:required + small:invalid {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: So would I get rid of the required in the input?